# Current C++ Best Practices & IDEs

Tags: .net, c++, windows

I've been living under a Java rock for about 5 years now. I suddenly have the need to write a Windows-only program that I believe would be best suited as either pure C++/Windows or C++.NET (I'm not sure which yet). The reason is because I need to do all sorts of very OS-specific (Windows-specific) operations that wouldn't make sense in the Java world.

So I ask, say I discover that .NET is not right for my project (this is to be determined). So then my only other alternative is to write a C++/Windows application. What's the IDE of choice these days?

Comment: The IDE of choice for pure Windows development is Visual Studio.  Obviously this is mostly a matter of personal preference, but I've found Visual Studio to offer the most advanced features specifically in terms of debugging (and remote debugging).

Comment: IDE of choice for windows? Visual Studio. But maybe you mean API of choice?

Comment: I'd agree.  C# will be the closest thing to the Java world for you, and will have nice libraries for everything you need just like the C++ .NET would.

Comment: You didn't specify which kind of program you are going to write; your IDE choices will likely be effected by that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Visual Studio 2010 or free alternative Visual Studio Express

http://www.microsoft.com/express

Answer (score 1):

If you develop on Windows anyway, then Visual Studio is a great choice for an IDE.

By the way, as you're used to Java, .NET using C# might be a better choice for you than C++. And it should give you nearly all the OS features you need, although I have not much experience with .NET I have to admit.

But if you really want to use C++, don't bother with the plain Win32 API or even MFC. Qt is a much better choice and is even platform-independent. Or use .NET with C++/CLI, but then you can also just use C#, which is a much more natural choice for .NET, especially when coming from a Java background.

But no matter if C++ or C#, Visual Studio is IMHO the best IDE on Windows, especially in conjunction with .NET.

Comment: And the downvote was due to ...? Appending other useful information to a though subjective but still perfectly valid IDE suggestion? Or maybe a personal dislike of Visual Studio/C++/C#/.NET/Qt? :(

Answer (score 1):

The best Windows IDE is Visual Studio which comes from Microsoft itself. As for best practices, here's some articles that I've found useful. They are not the end-all-be-all by any stretch of the imagination, but they are good guidelines, overall:
► http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml
► http://geosoft.no/development/cppstyle.html

Answer (score 0):

While Visual Studio is certainly the IDE of choice for Windows development, I think C# may be a viable option for your project. You say you're a Java developer, so working with C# will be more comfortable than, say, C++.NET. Plus, C# offers a lot of good APIs for working with Windows through .NET. Depending on your project, C# seems like a possible third alternative based on your description.

Comment: The question wasn't about which language to use, it was about an IDE. Moreover, the best IDE for C# ... is still Visual Studio.